# Word DDE call ignored

Tags: ms-word, dde, c++builder-xe

I am calling from my C++ code two DDE commands:

```
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[AddAddIn \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-trunk\\bin\\ws.dot\", 1][FileOpen .Name = \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-32x\\doc\\MyDoc.doc\]",false)
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[ToolsMacro .Name = \"FillTemplateAttests\", .Run]", false)
```

First command open template ws.dot and document MyDoc.doc. Template ws.dot contains macro *FillTemplateAttests* which I try to execute in second DDE command call. These two commands were functioning correctly more than 3 months. A few days ago second command interrupted functioning. I havent change anything in this part of code or in macro *FillTemplateAttests*. Interrupted functioning means that when I call second command nothing happens even when *ExecuteMacro* call returns true (which means all should be OK according to [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DdeMan.TDdeClientConv.ExecuteMacro)). When I run the same program with the same documents ws.dot and MyDoc.doc on another computer all is OK. When I call the second command twice it is actually executed (but only once - first call is ignored):

```
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[AddAddIn \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-trunk\\bin\\ws.dot\", 1][FileOpen .Name = \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-32x\\doc\\MyDoc.doc\]",false)
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[ToolsMacro .Name = \"FillTemplateAttests\", .Run]", false)
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[ToolsMacro .Name = \"FillTemplateAttests\", .Run]", false)
```

It seems to me like Word installation is broken. Could you help to find me the core of problem?

**ADDENDUM:**

When I call these 3 commands in row, all of them are executed:

```
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[AddAddIn \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-trunk\\bin\\ws.dot\", 1][FileOpen .Name = \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-32x\\doc\\MyDoc.doc\]",false)
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[Beep]", false);
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[ToolsMacro .Name = \"FillTemplateAttests\", .Run]", false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem even when I don't know why:

```
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[AddAddIn \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-trunk\\bin\\ws.dot\", 1][FileOpen .Name = \"C:\\Projects\\wscs-32x\\doc\\MyDoc.doc\]",false)
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[]", false);
FormDde->DdeClientConv1->ExecuteMacro("[ToolsMacro .Name = \"FillTemplateAttests\", .Run]", false)
```